# Getting a list of text concatenated in a group by

Tags: sql

Say I have this data:

```
site cell value
a    b    "1"
a    c    "2"
```

And I want the output for the format:

```
site value
a    "b=1,c=2"
```

Is it possible with SQL?

PS: I am using access. But even if access does not support this particular syntax I would like to know any database that can.

Comment: It is possible to write a VBA function that takes a `site` and returns the concatenated string, reading off a private recordset. This function can then be used from SQL (within Access, not via a data access library such as ADODB or ADO.NET). Does that count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @tbl table ([site] nvarchar(100),Cell nvarchar(100),Value nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl values('A','b','1')
INSERT INTO @tbl values('A','c','2')

SELECT [Site],
SUBSTRING(
(
select ' ,'+  Cell +'=' + CAST(value AS VARCHAR)
from @tbl b
WHERE a.[Site] = b.[Site]
FOR XML PATH('')
)
,3,100)

FROM @tbl a
GROUP BY a.[Site]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this in MySQL with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)